# What in WiFi configuration can prevent mobile device from connecting to wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to discover, why one of me Windows Phone based phones is not able to connect<sup>1</sup> to my home WiFi network. I [tested the phone itself](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12267/11237) and it turned out, that it connects without any problems to other WiFi network, so it seems, that problem is somewhere in router configuration, not in phone itself.

My current wireless network configuration (as read directly from router):

- SSID broadcast: **no**.
- 802.11 Mode: **802.11b/g Mixed**.
- Channel (ETSI): **Automatic**.
- Encryption: **AES**.
- Network Authentication: **Open System Authentication**.
- Security: **WPA2**.
- Authentication Method: **Pre-Shared Key**.
- Encryption Algorithm: **AES**.
- Group Key Update Interval: **(*unchecked*; 0 seconds)**.

My router configuration was different, when initially asking this question (in particular: *Channels* was set to some fixed value, *Encryption* was set to *AES+TKIP* and *Security* was set to *WPA+WPA2*). I found all this settings weird and changed them to above.

I have another device, Lark Ultimate 7i tablet with Windows 10, on which I was observing exactly the same problems. Changing router configuration from initial to above solved problem for tablet, but Lumia 735 still is unable to access my wireless network.

Can someone shed some light, on what can be the problem? Or what seems suspicious in router configuration presented above?

<sup>1</sup><sub>By "unable to access" I mean, that Lumia is initially correctly detecting my wireless network and it is correctly recognizing it as WPA2, as it is asking me to provide my WPA2 key. Once key (validated three times as correct) is provided, after about 30 seconds Lumia claims, that my network stopped responding. If I intentionally provide an incorrect WPA2 key, then Lumia is able to detect it and display error about wrong WPA key instead. But, once correct WPA key is provided then it again claims, that network stopped responding. Each attempt to reconnect this network (either directly or after phone and/or router restart) ends with the same story happening again, i.e. network is found, security is detected, request for providing WPA key is displayed and when key is provided, device again and again claims, that network stopped responding.</sub>

Comment: I suspect it is encryption related... If you temporarily disable security can the devices connect properly?

Comment: Just do AES without TKIP

Comment: You may also need to "forget this network" (or equivalent) on the phone.   Encrypted connections don't store the password the first time, the negotiate a key value and store that instead. It's possible the network is recognized but with a bad key

Comment: @Moab and acejavelin OMG! You might be right. I have just realized, that my other WiFi network (to which this phone connects without problems) uses pure AES, without TKIP. I'll do some tests and confirm that. If this turns out to be true, then we'll have a perfect answer for others. It is really strange for me, that low-cost Lumia 535 can connect to both networks (with and without TKIP), while medium-cost Lumia 735 can't (and only connects to AES without TKIP), but it seems, that this might be true. I'll let you know later.

Comment: @Tyson Thanks for your guide, however I have nothing to remove or "forget", because than network is not added to list of managed WiFi networks on my phone. I assume, that since phone is unable to connect it even with first attempt, it is also not able to exchange keys and store it and thus does not add network to the list. But, thanks for an additional info here.